# ember link-to from the component

Tags: templates, ember.js, routes, components

i am new at EmberJs.

I tried to link from the component "invoices-list" to invoice.

**invoices-list.hbs**

```
{{#each invoices as |invoice|}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{invoice.kdnr}}</td>
    <td>{{invoice.rnr}}</td>
    <td>{{invoice.invoiceId}}</td>
    <td>**{{#link-to 'invoice' invoice.invoiceId}}Click here{{/link-to}}**</td>
  </tr>
{{else}}
    <p>No datas</p>
{{/each}}
```

**invoices.hbs**

```
{{invoices-list invoices=model}}
```

**router.js**

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('invoices');
  this.route('invoice', { path: '/invoice/:invoice_id' });
});
```

My problem is, the template will not rendered and i get the error: "props.parentView.appendChild is not a function"

What is wrong?

Thanks for help.
Fabian

Comment: `this.route('invoice', { path: '/invoice/:invoiceId' });`  instead of `this.route('invoice', { path: '/invoice/:invoice_id' });` ..this may not solve your problem but i am suspecting do you  get the invoiceId param in invoice route.  may be check this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8489aa289f7fe61165a81fe260acd28f?openFiles=router.js%2Ctemplates.components.invoices-list.hbs&route=%2Finvoice%2F2)

Comment: demonstrate your issue with [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com) so that we can exactly fix your issue. since your code should work afaik.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you first an example how to use Link-to

Suppose this is your Route.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('photos', function(){
    this.route('edit', { path: '/:photo_id' });
  });
});
```

and this is app/templates/photos.hbs

```
<ul>
  {{#each photos as |photo|}}
    <li>{{#link-to "photos.edit" photo}}{{photo.title}}{{/link-to}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

then rendered HTML would be

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/photos/1">Happy Kittens</a></li>
  <li><a href="/photos/2">Puppy Running</a></li>
  <li><a href="/photos/3">Mountain Landscape</a></li>
</ul>
```

so in your case this is Route

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('invoices');
  this.route('invoice', { path: '/invoice/:invoice_id' });
});
```

then you may use this

```
{{#each invoices as |invoice|}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{invoice.kdnr}}</td>
    <td>{{invoice.rnr}}</td>
    <td>{{#link-to 'invoice' invoice}}{{/link-to}}</td>
  </tr>
{{else}}
    <p>No datas</p>
{{/each}}
```

another example to clarify:

```
//Route.js
this.route('contacts');
this.route('contact', { path: 'contacts/:contact_id' });

 //Contacts.hbs
    {{#each model as |contact|}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{link-to contact.name 'contact' contact}}</td>
          <td>{{link-to contact.email  'contact' contact}}</td>
          <td>{{contact.country}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
```

Hope it works for you. [more info.](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/templates/links/)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. But i have always the error.

Comment: https://ember-twiddle.com/630b8e0b575ebd26967ab68502539917?route=%2Finvoices thats run ..
But local not..i don't understand this

Comment: i create a new emper app and now run the app.

Comment: has your problem solved?It seems ok on your live version.r